# Basic authentication -H2 console login problem

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

If I click test connection it is getting successful but If I click connect,Iam getting like this.

1. http.csrf().disable();
2. http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

Even If I add these lines ,IDE is showing that these lines are Unused Property.So anyone help me with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.